# Wrong object type: 7 ERROR: WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered-set aggregate mode in laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

hello all I have a problem here message from sentry.io ERROR: WITHIN GROUP is required for ordered set set aggregate mode, I develop in production and production with the same code, in develop there are no problems that occur but in production there are errors like that Is it because of the database version difference or because my code has an error?

```
 $vendor  = DB::table('master.vendor_client as cv')
                    ->leftJoin('master.vendor as fv','fv.id','=','cv.vendor_id')
                    ->select('cv.*','fv.name','fv.mode','fv.vendor_type')
                    ->orderBy('cv.id')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: what is the purpose of use `master.` in here?

Comment: table vendor_client and vendor in schema master